# Tableau Subscription email should stop if the report is empty or job failed

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

We send out Tableau reports via subscription emails in our organization some are daily reports and some are monthly.
Problem/issue is empty reports are being sent if the data is not uploaded on time and also it is happening when a sql job is failing.
Im trying to find an option or any extension where we can stop the emails from going out if the report is empty or if the data is not updated.

Tableau server version is 2022.3.2

I tried an option by creating an extract of the data source and selected the schedule as when data extract refreshes to test it out i failed the job manually and checked but still it sent out an email with the empty report.

I was expecting the email to stop from going out.

Comment: Do you send out the reports via the menu items on the server admin page, or do you do that programmatically via some code? Doing this will be much easier with a codebase with access to both your Tableau Server and the SQL jobs.

Comment: @cSharp yes i sent out reports from the server using the subscription option from the menu. anyway thanks for the suggestion i definitely have to explore the option of doing it programmatically to check the possibilities.